# How can I get a centered column in VIm?

Tags: vim

I'd like to write Markdown in VIm just as if I were using those fancy mardown-editors like [Uberwriter](http://uberwriter.wolfvollprecht.de/) or [iA Writer](http://www.iawriter.com/ipad/). Of course, VIm is way more powerful, and that's why I'd rather use it. But I really miss the centered 80-char column of those apps. Can I get that in VIm? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim is a bare-bones text editor; very little in the UI appearance can be configured. That said, plugins like [DistractFree - An WriteRoom/DarkRoom/OmniWrite like plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4357) and [VimRoom](http://projects.mikewest.org/vimroom/) emulate a centered window with (invisible) scratch buffers to the left and right.

Comment: There is also focus.vim (https://gist.github.com/amacdougall/1989803)

Comment: VimRoom seems to be precisely what I need. Thanks a lot!